# Novice regular expression question

Tags: regex

I was wondering, how do I create create a regular expression that allows me to use something akin an "or" statement. For example,

```
^\w+? [\s?] OR [\\w\\W]*?]$
```

where the brackets represent the condition.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
(thing1|thing2)
```

This will match either "thing1" or "thing2" - [see here for more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

In your example it would be:

```
^(\w+? [\s?]|[\w\W]*?])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `|` between your groups.